# Focus color not change WPF changing enter like tab to move focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have datagrid with WPF. I have changed my focus control keyboard to make Enter like Tab so I can easily to change focus with Enter.

I used this code

```
 public static void PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //ganti enter dengan tab
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {

            if (Keyboard.FocusedElement is FrameworkElement)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                (Keyboard.FocusedElement as FrameworkElement).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }
        }
    }
```

And in mainwindow.xaml.cs I used this code

```
this.PreviewKeyDown += Tools.ToolsKeyboard.PreviewKeyDown;
```

But when I used in datagrid the focus color of current focus control is not changed like this picture :

[image: wpf focus]

How I can make the lost focus control in the first load to change to normal?

**UPDATE**

This is my datagrid style

```
  <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}" 
                   TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCDAFF" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />

                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>

        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Show your `DataGridCell` Style.

Comment: I have added my datagrid style..

Comment: Is there more to this style, or another style being used as well? I can't replicate your problem using the above code.

Comment: Take a look at this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't have any other style.. But when I used my Tab key it is normal but when using enter the problem is like that..

Comment: What I mean is, there's nothing in the above code that makes a single highlighted yellow cell.